# Does finding all locations in a region fill out unexplored areas of the map?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

In Xenoblade Chronicles 1, if you discovered every named location and landmark in a region any unexplored sections of the map would be filled in automatically.

Does the same apply to Xenoblade Chronicles 3? Will finding every landmark and named area fill in the map?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! An easy map to test this:

> While climbing the sword, the outer area does not have many POIs or waypoints; you can test it by finishing this area.

This is a very helpful way to finish off a certain gigantic map.

Comment: What needs to be found to fill out the map? Named locations? Landmarks? Secret areas? Quick travel points from defeating unique monsters?

Comment: From what I've gathered, every potential point of interest needs to be found, except for UM tombstones (I didn't kill the one in the spoilered map I mentioned).